# How can I avoid wrapping a bunch of functions inside useCallback when using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

I'm making a pixel drawing app. 
I have a canvas component which handles the drawing logic,
inside of which is the following useEffect:

```
...
useEffect(() => {

        // Pass reference of the canvas element to the parent component 
        setCanvasRef(canvasRef.current);

        // Mouse util -> add listeners and offset the coordinates relative to the drawing canvas element
        mouse.follow(canvasRef.current);

       
        // Add listeners (not using synthetic react listeners because I need to track events              
        // outside the canvas bounds)
    
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', executeCurrentState);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', executeCurrentState);
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', executeCurrentState);

        // Render initial pixel data to the canvas
        render();

        // Cleanup
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('mousedown', executeCurrentState);
            document.removeEventListener('mouseup', executeCurrentState);
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', executeCurrentState);
            mouse.removeListeners();
        };
        
    }, [setCanvasRef, mouse, render, executeCurrentState]);
...
```

React tells me to wrap the `render` and `executeCurrentState` functions inside a useCallback, 
But since these functions call other functions, I have to add those to the useCallback dependency array, and wrap them in a useCallback too. 
 It goes on like this recuresively until every function and property called by `render` and `executeCurrentState` is wrapped in useCallback.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: I am curious to know if it worked out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refering a function with a ref could work

```
   const SomeComponent = () => {

      const executeCurrentState = () => {  
        // use a prop or state
      }
 
      const executeCurrentStateRef = useRef();
      executeCurrentStateRef.current = executeCurrentState;

      useEffect(() => {
         ...
         const executeCurrentStateWrapper = (event) => {
              executeCurrentStateRef.current(event) // always points to latest function
         }

         document.addEventListener('mousedown', executeCurrentStateWrapper);
         ...
         return  () => {
             document.removeEventListener('mousedown', executeCurrentStateWrapper);
         }


      , [])
```

if you are using React 18 and want to try out their new (experimental) [useEvent hook](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/separating-events-from-effects#declaring-an-event-function)

```
  const executeCurrentState = useEvent(() => {
       // code for function in component render
   });

   useEffect(() => {

             document.addEventListener('mousedown', executeCurrentState);
             ...
             return  () => {
                 document.removeEventListener('mousedown', executeCurrentState);
             }

    }, []) // no dependencies needed for userEvent
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find a way to import the useEvent hook, but the wrapper solution works! 

Also I was wondering if 'executeCurrentState' and 'render' had to be added into the dependency array in the first place, since they don't effect the state in any way (they only handle parts of the pixel drawing logic)

Comment: Welcome, 
Each render has it own closures, 
https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-everything
Its a old article, but it will give you an idea of why dependencies are needed and how to avoid bugs,
even if the function dont change state, they could be refering to stale state, props and eventually someone will likely create a bug